# Setting min and max zoom levels

Tags: android, zooming, osmdroid

Having trouble with the zoom interface using OSMDroid API- can not seem to get the zoom control to zoom beyond level 18.  Using a local ( SD card ) custom map cache with levels 12-22. We can zoom from 12 -18, but not beyond.  There doesn't seem to be any way to set the min or max zoom.  Anyone have any ideas on where this setting is defined?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make a class extending MapView, there you can set it by overriding the getMaxZoomLevel() and getMinZoomLevel(), like this:

```
public class CustomMapView extends MapView {

/* constructors */  

@Override
public int getMaxZoomLevel() {
    return 22;
}

@Override
public int getMinZoomLevel() {
    return 12;
}

}
```

don't forget to change the MapView call to CustomMapView in your layout:

```
<com.yourpackage.CustomMapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

and activity:

```
private CustomMapView mMapView;
.
.
.
mMapView = (CustomMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```